# Datacontext of nested user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ninject, caliburn

Background :-

I have a wpf view containing a combobox which gets populated by the view model using caliburn micro / ninject and mvvm pattern; this view also contains a stackpanel area. When the user selects the appropriate option from the combobox I insert the appropriate user control into the stackpanel presenting the user with a seemless transition to the related display.

Each "nested" user control which gets displayed in the stackpanel has it's own view model automatically associated by caliburn micro.

Problem :-

The "nested" user control bindings all try and refer back to the parent view model and not the view model associated with them specifically.

I can, initially, work around this by specifying :-

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:UserControlSpecificViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

but this requires a parameterless constructor in the view model but I need to be able to have paremeters passed to this view model so that Ninject can inject objects such as EventAggregator.

Going around in ciricles as I am fairly new to WPF so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

James.

Comment: what kind of parameters do you need to pass to the view model?

Comment: Hi - mainly IEventAggregator

Comment: @xnetdude. last time I looked at caliburn (its been awhile!) I thought it had the concept of a view model with children view models baked into the architecture. Presumeably they would know how to reach their parent, but I don't know. Have you posted this question on caliburn's codeplex forum?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem could be to just initialize your view model in code behind and call the appropriate constructor. If you have a dislike of code behind in your WPF applications then I suppose you could possibly just bind your view model to the `IEventAggregator` object.

XAML:

```
<UserControl1 x:Name="myUserControl">
</UserControl>
```

Codebehind:

```
public MainWindow() // Constructor for window
{
    InitializeContext();
    MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel(...);
    myUserControl.DataContext = vm;
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply.  I am very new to WPF so would you mind giving an example of binding the view model to the IEventAggregator?

Comment: Can you provide some code as to how you are initializing the `IEventAggregator`?

Comment: namespace MyApp.Application.Bootstrapping
{
    public class ApplicationModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            // Required Caliburn Micro objects
            Bind<IWindowManager>().To<ApplicationWindowManager>().InSingletonScope();
            Bind<IEventAggregator>().To<EventAggregator>().InSingletonScope();
            
            // Automapper BootStrapper
            Bind<IBootStrapper>().To<MapperBootStrapper>();
        }
    }
}

Comment: sorry about the formatting - will try and work out how to post correctly

Comment: Since you have all this code behind anyway, I'm guessing you don't care about adding one more line to your code behind. In your window's constructor, just create and initialize the view model and then set it to be the data context for your user control. You will obviously need to name your user control to access it from code behind.

Comment: This is all done from the bootstrapper but there is no code behind on the view/view model.